# How to remove unchecked warning for Fluent interface default methods

Tags: java, fluent

I was wondering if there's a way of removing the unchecked warning for the following code which provides a fluent API that returns itself.

```
public interface Taggable<T> {

    /**
     * Should return the underlying set that holds the tags.
     *
     * @return set
     */
    Set<String> getTags();

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    default T tag(@NotNull String... tags) {
        for (String tag : tags) {
            getTags().add(tag);
        }
        return (T) this;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    default T untag(@NotNull String tag) {
        getTags().remove(tag);
        return (T) this;
    }

}
```

Usage would be

```
@Data
public class MyObject implements Taggable<MyObject> {
   private Set<String> tags;
}

MyObject t = new MyObject()
   .tag("abc")
   .tag("def");
```

Working example with suppress warnings https://repl.it/@trajano/fluent

Comment: no, T is the type that contains a set

Comment: You just want to get rid of the `@SuppressWarnings`?

Comment: @daniu yes (if it is possible)  So far it's looking that it isn't.

Answer (score 1):

```
public interface Taggable<T extends Taggable<T>>
```

And change

```
(T) this
```

to

```
this
```

So:

```
default Taggable<T> tag(@NotNull String... tags) {
    Collections.addAll(getTags(), tags);
    return this;
}
```

This is what the base class Enum (for all enum classes) does.

A fluent API, the builder pattern, in general is a bit more verbose.
The advantage however not having such artifacts as `getTags`.
Delegation to an tag/untag interface implementation would seem better.

Comment: I just tried this, it is still flagging as unchecked.

Comment: Without the cast `(T)` ? as `this` now is a Taggable.

Comment: @ArchimedesTrajano You also need to declare `default Taggable<T> tag(...)` and then just `return this`.

Comment: then you get the same issue from the answer that was already deleted. making this change gives errors like Taggable<MyObject> cannot be converted to MyObject

Comment: @JoopEggen where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Taggable<T> declared in interface Taggable
Taggable.java:21: error: incompatible types: Taggable<T> cannot be converted to T
    return this;

Comment: @ArchimedesTrajano thanks for the effort too. I now hesitate whether whether chaining with other MyObject methods is still possible.

Comment: Anyone want to just claim it isn't possible so I can give them the rep? :)